# Align My Html Contents In top for PDF

Tags: c#, itext

My Contents are downloading in pdf correctly. But I cant able to fix the alignment in PDF Itextsharp Coding.

My Pdf code

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f);
```

In this what i Need to change for My contents Need to show from TOP .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings works for me.

```
Document ResultPDF = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 25, 10, 20, 30);
        Write.PageEvent = new MyPdfPageEventHelpPageNo();


//Those below can improve the layout and functions of the pdf you create
        PdfPTable Headtable = new PdfPTable(7);
        Headtable.TotalWidth = 525f;
        Headtable.LockedWidth = true;
        Headtable.HeaderRows = 5;
        Headtable.FooterRows = 2;
        Headtable.KeepTogether = true;
        Headtable.SetExtendLastRow(false, true);
```

Hope they solve your problem

EDIT

To solve the Write.PageEvent

```
PdfWriter Write = PdfWriter.GetInstance(ResultPDF, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~") + "/PDF/Results/" + fileName, FileMode.Create));
```

This alows you to save the file on the server if you want. I always do this.

Cant say 100% why the `Headtable.SetExtendLastRow(false, true);` shows an error. try hover your mouse over the error in your coding program and look at what the error tells you.

Comment: HI,  In this Write.PageEvent and HeadTable.SetExtendedLastRow() showing error. Can You Please give your Full Coding

Comment: Thanks . and i want to save the pdf file in my project folder instead of downloading .